# Failed to connect to BigQuery with Python - Deadline of 600.0s exceeded while calling target function

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm connecting google bigquery via vpn, but the strange thing is that the following code can connect bq successfully when run on the cloud shell, but it always shows a timeout when run locally. The error returned is: google.api_core.exceptions.ServiceUnavailable: 503 failed to connect to all addresses; last error: UNKNOWN: tcp handshaker shutdown

Here is my code which was running

```
bq_client = bigquery.Client()
predict_df = bq_client.query(query_predict_sql).to_dataframe()
```

I have used gcloud auth application-default login for local authorization, the version of python is 3.10.13, google-cloud-bigquery 3.13.0. The same problem occurs on cloud sql, and the connection is successfully on cloud shell. In addition, my java service can successfully connect to bigquery and cloud sql locally.

Any advices?
Thanks for your help in advance